# how to print set of values in like an array? i dont want to print all the values just i want to print no. of letters

Tags: arrays, c, string, integer, cs50

i want to print the number of letters in the text . like letters:6, letters :5, if there are 6 letters it is printing 123456 or if 5 letters it is printing 12345. i want to print no of letters like letter:6 or letter:5

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){ int letter=0; int words=0; int sentences=0;

string para =get_string("Text:");

for(int i=0;i<strlen(para);i++){

if((para[i]>='a' || para[i]<='z') && (para[i]>='A' || para[i]<='Z') && (para[i]!=' ')) {
letter++;

    printf("%i",letter);
}
}

//printf("%s",para);

}
```

here is the output

Text:text is
123456~/ $

Comment: Move the `printf` statement outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have your print statement inside your for loop, just move it outside and then add whatever you want to the print statement. You can also just use isalpha() to check whether or not a character is a letter or not. Google "C isalpha() tutorialspoint" for more details.

So from this:

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(para);i++){

if((para[i]>='a' || para[i]<='z') && (para[i]>='A' || para[i]<='Z') && (para[i]!=' ')) 
letter++;

    printf("%i",letter);
}
```

To this

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(para);i++){

if((para[i]>='a' || para[i]<='z') && (para[i]>='A' || para[i]<='Z') && (para[i]!=' ')) 
letter++;

}
printf("Letters: %i",letter);
```

Comment: You should improve the indentation in your proposed solution and (more importanly) address the issue of a missing closing brace (`}`) ... I can see two `{` but only one `}`. As it stands, the `printf` statement is **still inside** the `for` loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).